# How to change tabs images ( not in pressed )?

Tags: android, android-tabs

I'm already built custom tabs only with images and now i need to change this tabs images when user switch from **Arabic\English** button from another activity and

here is my code to get tabs from tab activity

```
mainTabs =  ((TabActivityMy) getParent()).getTabHost(); 
    mainTabs.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = mainTabs.newTabSpec(null);
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator,  ((TabActivityMy) getParent()).getTabHost().getTabWidget(), false);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    mainTabs.addTab(spec);
```

when i do this app add new tabs i know this code is do that but i just need to change images for all current tabs

[image]

Comment: http://store1.up-00.com/2013-12/1386590546791.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to remove all the views from tabhost first:

```
mainTabs =  ((TabActivityMy) getParent()).getTabHost(); 
mainTabs.removeAllViews()

mainTabs.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
TabHost.TabSpec spec = mainTabs.newTabSpec(null);
View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator,  ((TabActivityMy)    getParent()).getTabHost().getTabWidget(), false);
ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
spec.setContent(intent);
mainTabs.addTab(spec);
```

Try removing allviews from TabWidget:

```
mainTabs.getTabWidget().removeAllViews();
```

There is function:

```
mainTabs.clearAllTabs();
```

This should work in your case

Comment: i'm also try to do that but app crash and i think app crash because i removed the current view also :) , right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of your language switch and set the image resources based on it..

**for example:**

```
 if(lamguage==english)
 your_imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_english_image);
 else
 your_imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_arabic_image);
```

Comment: already i'm doing that in main tab activity , but now i'm in another activity and have a button when i press on it store new value in shared preferences and change custom action bar and must also change tabs images , code i inserted here is for adding new tabs to the parent but i'm only need to change imges for current tabs

Comment: Are you using TabHost?